# Connection attempt failed when connecting to online mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

So I'm making a register page for a website. and I have to send data to that database. The problem is that the database is being hosted and I don't know how to connect to it. this is my code so far : (Note that I did leave out the password for security reasons.)

```
   if(isset($_POST['register'])){

      if(isset($_POST['voornaam'], $_POST['tussenvoegsel'], 
      $_POST['achternaam'], $_POST['straat'], $_POST['huisnummer'], 
      $_POST['postcode'], $_POST['woonplaats'], $_POST['telefoon'], 
      $_POST['mobiel'], $_POST['e-mail'], $_POST['wachtwoord'], 
      $_POST['rekeningnummer']))
    {
//personal info
$voornaam        = $_POST['voornaam'];
$tussenvoegsel   = $_POST['tussenvoegsel'];
$achternaam      = $_POST['achternaam'];

//contact info
$straat          = $_POST['straat'];
$huisnummer      = $_POST['huisnummer'];
$postcode        = $_POST['postcode'];
$woonplaats      = $_POST['woonplaats'];
$telefoon        = $_POST['telefoon'];
$mobiel          = $_POST['mobiel'];

//account info 
$wachtwoord      = $_POST['wachtwoord'];
$hash            = password_hash($wachtwoord, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

$email           = $_POST['e-mail'];
$rekeningnummer  = $_POST['rekeningnummer'];



//link naar remote database.
$link = mysqli_connect("databases.000webhost.com", "", "", "");

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_errno());
    exit();
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, Tussenvoegsel, Achternaam, Straat, Huisnummer, Postcode, Woonplaats, Telefoon, Mobiel, Email, Rekeingnummer)
        VALUES('$voornaam', '$hash', '$tussenvoegsel', '$achternaam', '$straat', '$huisnummer', '$postcode', '$woonplaats', '$telefoon', '$mobiel', '$email', '$rekeningnummer')";

mysqli_query($link, $sql);
mysqli_close($link);



}
}
```

this code gives me an error. the error says :

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   respond correctly after a certain period of time, or the connection
>   that was made failed because the connected host did not respond

I hope someone can help me with this. I've been stuck here for some time now.

Comment: 000webhost does not allows remote connection to databases, you need to connect using `localhost` and files to be hosted on `files.000webhost.com`. btw, you may wish to hide those db credentials from this post.

Comment: it is really a bad approach. make some APIs and communicate with them using APIs

Comment: @Arvind I don't really get your approach with localhost and a hosted file. what exactly do you mean?

Comment: If 000webhost allows outside connections make sure your DB-user is allowed to connect from outside and not just from localhost

Answer (score 4):

Please check this code to connect to your database.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost"; // Your database server name
$username = "username"; // Your database user name which you use to connect
$password = "password"; // Your database password

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

This should solve your problem. If not then please try to connect with database server from your web server manually from terminal by doing below command.

```
mysql -u username -p your_dbname
```

After this command press enter and it will ask for password, You have to enter your password here.

If this command connects to your db then your php code should also work. Just check whether the credentials you are using are correct or not.

Comment: I left the credentials out this code for security reasons, but i'm 100% sure the credentials are correct.

Comment: Did you tried manually to connect database server from your web server ? by doing given command ?

Comment: I did not, because I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Ohh, From where this code is executing ? from production or local ? if local then open your command prompt and hit this command. if it is production then first you need to connect production server using ssh and hit this command from there.

Comment: By looking into error that you have got it seems your web server is not able to connect to database server, Just check you are using correct host name , database name, user , port of database server.

Comment: im doing this from my local server. i will try to do it using the command prompt.